# JQL to Python Date format Conversion

Tags: python, date, jql

Im trying to pull data from JIRA and convert using Python to a MM-DD-YYY Format and getting this error

```
ValueError: time data '2021-05-14T06:24:12.591-0500' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'
```

Can anyone advise what I need to use for the Date format parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string you provided is completely wrong. For instance in your input, the year comes first but in the format you specify that the date will be in format d/m/y. (lowercase `y` doesn't include the century btw)

---

The easiest way is to use `dateutil.parser`:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('2021-05-14T06:24:12.591-0500')
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 14, 6, 24, 12, 591000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```